# Scheduled Phone Call in Bulk - Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

One of the job my organization has is to call the customer who created account on yesterday, two weeks ago and two months ago (3 times). I'm kinda new to Dynamics CRM, and this really make my head blown up. In my thinking (not necessarily true), there are two ways I can handle this task in Dynamics CRM:

- Create a target group of all customers who opened account yesterday and scheduled a campaign with Due Date to be today, two weeks-1 from now and 2 months - 1 from now. (don't know how to schedule phone call in bulk in Campaign)
- Create a dynamic target group for all customers who opened an account yesterday OR two weeks ago OR two months ago, and add all to a phone call campaign. (don't know how to specify this target group based on Advanced Find query)

Any help to save my misery life would be much appreciated, and I'll make sure to vote up for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this on Dynamics CRM forum and was answered. This is exactly what I need, so I just quote his post here. Credit to  PRASHANT SHUKLA at https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/113995.aspx

> Hi There,
>
> Here you go  !!
>
> You can create three different workflows.
>
> Create  workflows on entity account. Add step wait condition, under
>   this condition select process then timeout then 1 day after created on
>   or 14 days after created on or 60 days after created on....save &
>   close.
>
> Next step (add) Create Record select phone call & set properties.
>
> This will work for you, try it & let me know if you have any doubt.
>
> If you found my post helpful, plz mark it as verified.
>
> CRM-tude
>
> Prashant Shukla